# Can I attach multiple sink configurations with a single Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I followed [this link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/) to configure Cassandra Sink with Kafka Connect.

In the blog post we first start Kafka Connect. Next we post our CassandraSink configurations to Kafka Connect.

```
java -jar kafka-connect-cli-0.5-all.jar create cassandra-sink-orders < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties
```

**Connector `cassandra-sink-orders`:**

```
name=cassandra-sink-orders
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=orders-topic
connect.cassandra.export.route.query=INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM orders-topic
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.key.space=demo
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.username=cassandra
connect.cassandra.password=cassandra
```

Now I have want to attach a different configurations with the same Kafka Connect. When I do so the previous WorkerSink gets detached. Is there a way that both of them can work in parallel with a single Kafka Connect. Or Do I need to start another Kafka Connect at some other port and attach the new configurations with it?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can either run:

1. Kafka Connect in *distributed mode* and have it run multiple connectors. This is valid for a single node deployment, and has the benefit of being simple to scale out—you just add more nodes and Kafka Connect handles the distribution of workload. Use the REST API to control Kafka Connect configuration, [as shown here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) and [documented here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode).
2. Kafka Connect in *standalone mode*, and pass a [series of connector configs as commandline arguments](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#standalone-mode).